# Exponent function implementation

Tags: python

Why is the below code is not working when a negative input is provided?

**Code**

```
a = input("Enter the number to determine the exponent? ")

def expo(n):

    print(f'Value of n is {n}')
    if (n>=0):
        return 10**n
    else:
        print(f'In this loop')
        #print(f'Value = {(1/(10**n)}')
        return (1/(10**n))
e= expo(int(a))
print(f'Value of exponent of {a} is {e}')
```

output

```
Enter the number to determine the exponent? -2
Value of n is -2
In this loop
Value of exponent of -2 is 100.0
```

Comment: It's not `1/(10**abs(n))` ?

Comment: By the way, else statements are not "loops"

Comment: Just `10**n` already does what `expo` is supposed to do. By doing `1/10**n` for negative `n` you undo the effect of the negative sign.

Comment: If your goal is to reimplement exponentiation as an exercise, then using `**` seems like cheating. If not, then just use `10 ** n` which works for both positive and negative values..

Answer (score 0):

Simply add negative sign to else statement exponent

```
 a = input("Enter the number to determine the exponent? ")
    
    def expo(n):
        print(f'Value of n is {n}')
        if (n>=0):
            return 10**n
        else:
            print(f'In this loop')
        #print(f'Value = {(1/(10**n)}')
        return 1/((10**(-n)))
    
    e= expo(int(a))
    print(f'Value of exponent of {a} is {e}')
```

Comment: `1/((10**(-n)))` is a needlessly complicated way to write `10**n`, which makes the `if` statement (and the whole `expo` function) unnecessary.

Comment: yes, there are many more elegant ways of writing this, but question was what is wrong with given code.